# Sieve of Eratosthenes using sqrt AND ceil

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Currently I'm trying to write a python script to simulate the Sieve of Eratosthenes. The problem is, the professor is requiring us to use both math.sqrt and math.ceil, and then run the following tests:

```
assert sieve(2) == [2]
assert sieve(3) == [2, 3]
assert sieve(4) == [2, 3]
assert sieve(5) == [2, 3, 5]
```

and

```
try:
    sieve(0)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    raise AssertionError("Did not raise")

try:
    sieve(-4)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    raise AssertionError("Did not raise")
```

I have only able to get the code to work when writing the script without using either sqrt or ceil, but without either, the Try/Except test won't pass because only taking the square root of values 0 and -4 would throw the ValueError........ Any suggestions?

What i'm currently working with:

```
def sieve(n):
    myList = []
    primeList = []
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in myList:
            primeList.append(i)
            for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
                myList.append(j)
    return primeList
print(sieve(-4))
```

This then returns

```
[]
```

instead of a ValueError.

EDIT:
We're also not allowed to hard-code in an error like that.

As requested, here is the other script I've been fiddling with, but it still does not throw an error when entering zero, and fails the assert tests

```
def sieve3(n):
    marked = {}
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, int(ceil(sqrt(n)))):
        if not marked.get(i):
            for x in range(i * i, n, i):
                marked[x] = True
    for i in range(2, n):
        if not marked.get(i):
            primes.append(i)
    print(primes)

sieve3(100)
```

Comment: To get a ValueError it seems like you need to pass sqrt with a negative argument. The other option would have been to have division by zero but that gives ZeroDivisionError. This seems you need something like int(ceil(sqrt(n-1))) somewhere in the code or such like. You may find that the seive works with this condition as the square of a number can never be prime.

Comment: Thank you Salix, this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding an additional variable of:

```
m = int(ceil(sqrt(n-1)))
```

causing an input of 0 to return a ValueError.

credit to Salix alba for their comment.